# Can I import existing PDF books into Kindle for PC?

Tags: pdf, kindle

I have a touchscreen laptop and Kindle for PC works great as a ebook reader with touch functionality. However I have several PDFs books which I would like to import and read using Kindle for PC. How do I import existing PDF books into Kindle for PC?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kindle DX natively supports PDF files. If, however,  you have a First generation Kindle, then you can convert the PDF to a .prc file using the [Mobipocket eBook Creator](http://www.mobipocket.com/en/DownloadSoft/ProductDetailsCreator.asp)

You could also use Amazon's [Kindle Personal Documents Service](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200140600&).

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. However, I dont own the device. I downloaded Kindle for PC and would like to read PDFs on my touch screen laptop

Comment: Apologies, I misread your question. I'm afraid, as far as I know, it doesn't support PDF files, you will have to convert them using one of the methods I mentioned above.

Comment: like Pulse noted above, use the Mobipocket eBook Createor to create the .prc files and then copy them to My Documents\Kindle Books\. Restart Kindle for PC and all .prc books are now available in Kindle

Answer (score 16):

Right click on the PDF and open with *Kindle for PC*.

If the option isn't there then browse and select the *Kindle for PC* shortcut from its location (desktop, documents, etc). This will permanently put the PDF in your Kindle library.

Comment: Mine was installed here: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Amazon\Kindle\application\Kindle.exe`

Comment: really did not expect this to work, but surprise! it does.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also like to recommend [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) for any Linux users.

It manages, transfers and converts between various eBook formats.

Answer (score -2):

You can also add the pdf to you're my kindle content folder under documents and when you re start kindle for pc it will show up in you're library in the kindle.